# How to set a Custom typing shortcut?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, shortcuts

I want to set a shortcut for my terminal window so that when I type terminal in desktop it will open. Is there any way to make a custom typing shortcut? Like WWW and something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very useful bash alias for that. Edit or create the file `~/.bash_aliases`.  Then state your aliases like below, entering one alias per line.

Here are a few examples

```
alias www='chromium-browser'
alias wwwproxy='chromium-browser --proxy-server=a.b.com:1234'
alias myserver='ssh myname@mysshserver.com'
```

Then, in your terminal, you can call these shortcuts

```
$ www 
    -- Opens chromium with a blank or home page
$ wwwproxy disney.com 
    -- Opens disney.com in chromium using a proxy
$ myserver 
    -- connects to your ssh server
```

Comment: @user689893---nice answer

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at system->preferences->keyboard shortcuts.

Default shortcut for terminal is alt+ctrl+t

you can set your custom shortcuts.